# Regex validator on form seems to interfere with max_length validation on Charfield

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to validate input for a form field as a numbers only with 12-14 digits and which may have leading zeros.

However when I add the below regex validator for numbers to my form field it seems to interfere whenever there is a max_length set on the form and it fails validation.

```
only_numbers = RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')

mpan_lower = forms.CharField(label='some_label',
    help_text=mark_safe('Help text with link. '
                        '<a href="#">  Need more help?</a>'),
                        validators=[
                                     only_numbers,
                                 ],
                                 max_length=14,
                                 )
```

[image]

Comment: Unfamiliar with django, but why would you need `max_length` if you already have the regex validator which specifies that the max length is 10?

Comment: @Mark because this is a `CharField` (it accepts any character). What the user needs is only digits, thus the regex. `max_length` defines the length of the characters.

Comment: @Mark When the length is wrong, the regex validator just says *Enter a valid value*, which doesn't tell you what is wrong. Setting `max_length` can give you useful error messages like *Ensure this value has at most 14 characters (it has 15)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r'^\d{1,10}$'`

This regex will allow between 1 and 10 digits. The string `12345678901234` has 14 digits so the regex validator will not accept it.

If you want between 12 and 14 digits, then use:

```
r'^\d{12,14}$'
```

Alternatively, you could use `r'^\d+$` (matches 1 or more digits), and validate the length another way (e.g. by setting `min_length` and `max_length` for your form field).

Comment: thanks is it possible to specify a regex which only specifies numbers and not how many digits?

Comment: Thanks ... silly errors I shoudl have done `r'^[\d]+$'` with the `max_length` and `min_length` attributes.

Comment: `r'^\d*$'` would match zero or more digits, and `r'^\d+$'` would match one or more digits.